# Textarea auto-resize to fit content when resizing browser window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a textarea that expands or contracts to fit the content as the **browser window is resized**. So when the browser window width increases, the height of the textarea should decrease so that it is as tall as the content; when the browswer window width decreases, the height of the textarea should increase to show all of the content. Here's what I have now, with reference to textareas that expand with content input:

```js
var tx = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
for (let i = 0; i < tx.length; i++) {
  tx[i].setAttribute("style", "height:" + (tx[i].scrollHeight) + "px;overflow-y:hidden;");
  window.addEventListener("resize", autoResize(tx[i]));
}

function autoResize(el) {
  el.style.height = "auto";
  el.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + "px";
}
```

How do I get this to work? 
*Edit: clarifying what I mean by auto-resize 
*Edit 2: I checked related questions but they all address how textareas resize with **user input**, whereas I'm asking how they resize when the **browser window is resized**. I'm new to Javascript so I don't know how to apply these solutions to my problem.

Comment: So you want the textarea to expand to 100% of the width and height of the browser window?

Comment: @fabian-s no. I want to make the textarea as tall as its content

Comment: I believe you will find this thread helpful.. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the textarea to expand depending on browser window, u can use viewport units.

Vh stands for 1% of the viewport height and vw for 1% of the viewport width.

```
100vh //100% of the viewport height
100vw //100% of the viewport width
```

Comment: Thank you. However, what I mean here is to make the textarea as tall as its content. I'm sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: [Is there a way to get a textarea to stretch to fit its content without using PHP or JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803880/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-textarea-to-stretch-to-fit-its-content-without-using-php)