# Desiging HTML forms

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Autosizing Textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477/autosizing-textarea)

Hi,

I have developed a web form where one field is description. I want that field to be bigger in size, so that users can see the full description. How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type of fields are you using? are you using input fields for the the description or have you used textarea's?

If you are using inputs rather use `<textarea cols="100" rows="5" id="yourID" name="yourNAME"></textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give a text area a specific width and height then I would recommend using style rather than `cols` or `rows`.

This is because different browsers will give different widths and heights with `cols` and `rows`.

To be as consistent as possible across multiple browsers you can use something like:

```
<textarea name="myTextarea" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;"></textarea>
```

Or to keep the HTML cleaner you could use:

```
<style type="text/css">
.myTextarea {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
</style>

<textarea name="myTextarea" class="myTextarea"></textarea>
```

If however I have mis-understood and you want the textarea to automatically grow in size, you would need to use javascript, or better yet something like jQuery, and the use of rows/cols would become much more important.