# Not working Javascript in any browser except IE

Tags: javascript

I have following code..

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
  <head runat="server">
  <title>Automatic Resize TextBox</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function setHeight(txtdesc) {
    txtdesc.style.height = txtdesc.scrollHeight + "px";
  }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesc" runat= "server" TextMode="MultiLine"  Onkeyup="setHeight(this);" onkeydown="setHeight(this);" />
   </div>
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

This is a javascript for Resize the Textbox while writing in text box.means if textbox will fill completely then it will be expand automatically but if we remove the textbox then the textbox will be collapsed...its working fine in IE but not in other browser plz help me....

Comment: I mean 2 say that if we remove text from textbox then it will auto matically collapsed...

Comment: If you have a client side problem, then show client side code, not server side code that will generate client side code when you execute it.

Comment: I m not able to get you can u plz give me brief words about this.........

Comment: Stop looking at ASP in a text editor. Go to the browser. View Source. Get the code the browser deals with. Show people that.

Comment: @user - he's saying use straight html `input` in your example instead of asp.net server control `asp:TextBox`.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
function setHeight(txtdesc) {
txtdesc.style.height = txtdesc.scrollHeight + "px";
}
</script>
 </head>

Comment: <body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="Default.aspx"        id="form1">
<div><input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE"       value="/wEPDwUJMjgzMDgzOTgzZGSXAQ2vP0KeMidKtP59K6K+VzcGtQ==" />    </div><div><input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION"  id="__EVENTVALIDATION"  value="/wEWAgLSzZDQAQL+1u+tAtrSF8i0a84NdQxgxn2wtnqRvEVQ" /></div>
<div><textarea name="txtDesc" rows="2" cols="20" id="txtDesc"      onkeyup="setHeight(this);" onkeydown="setHeight(this);"></textarea>    </div>

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/eT6tR/

I have found this working in Chrome and FF. If you still facing issue. write in details and paste client side code here means HTML+JS.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is that in IE the scrollHeight is calculated based on just the contents of the text area and in other browsers it is based on the available content space.  This means that setting the CSS height will increase the scrollHeight and prevent it from shrinking back down.

This question has come up many times and it looks like the best answer people have come up with is to perform the complicated task of calculating how many rows there would be based on the text content.  [See this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477/autosizing-textarea) and many others by searching.

[Here is an example you can look at using jQuery](http://www.technoreply.com/autogrow-textarea-plugin-version-2-0/).