# Automatic TextBox Width

Tags: asp.net, .net, html

There is a [similar thread about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477/autosizing-textarea-using-prototype).  But I want to have a multiline TextBox with automatic width (**fit width to the larger row**).

With this code I can have a multiline TextBox (automatic height)

```
     <div style="float:left; white-space:nowrap ">
        <asp:TextBox style="display:inline; overflow:hidden"  
                     ID="txt1" 
                     runat="server" 
                     Wrap="false" 
                     ReadOnly="true" 
                     TextMode="MultiLine" 
                     BorderStyle="none" 
                     BorderWidth="0">
        </asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server" Text="Example textbox"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
```

Code behind:

```
txt1.Rows= text.Split("|").Length ' Sets number of rows but with low performance
txt1.Text = text.Replace("|", Environment.NewLine)
```

Once again, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try a linq approach:

```
string[] rows = text.Split('|');
int maxLength = rows.Max(x => x.Length);

txt1.Rows = rows.Length;
txt1.Columns = maxLength;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using plugins like jquery, 
you should look at autoresize plugins.

These will resize as a user types too.

Check out one [autoresize](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('textarea').autosize();  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Joel Etherton give me a real good working code example of how to resolve this using Linq, but unfurtenly I can't use Linq.

**Multiline TextBox auto Width using Linq** (Joel Etherton's solution):
C#

```
string[] rows = text.Split('|');
int maxLength = rows.Max(x => x.Length);

txt1.Rows = rows.Length;
txt1.Columns = maxLength;
```

VB

```
    Dim rows() As String = text.Split("|")
    Dim maxLength As Integer = rows.Max(Function(x) x.Length)
    txt1.Rows = rows.Length
    txt1.Columns = maxLength
    text = text.Replace("|", Environment.NewLine)
    txt1.Text = text
```

**Multiline TextBox auto Width solution 2**
To achieve this "manually", I did this method to know the larger row's lenght. Is not the most efficiente one, but It worked for me:

```
    Dim textRows() As String = text.Split("|")

    For Each row As String In textRows
        row = row.Trim
        textToDisplay = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", textToDisplay, row, Environment.NewLine)
        If row.Length > maxRowLenght Then
            maxRowLenght = row.Length
        End If
    Next
    txt1.Rows = textRows.Length
    txt1.Columns = maxRowLenght
    txt1.Text = textToDisplay
```