# How do you create textareas where the height increases to fit the text?

Tags: html, css, textarea

I'm currently trying to create textareas to display dialogue in a screenplay format. So far, I've come up with this:

`<textarea style="width: 140pt; border: 0px; resize: none; overflow:hidden;">`

I've tried adding stuff like `height: auto;`, `overflow: auto;` or just removing the height altogether (as I have done in the code above) - but this hasn't worked. All I want it to do is increase the height of the textarea so that it fits its text, whilst keeping the width at 140pt. How should I do this?

Thanks, J

Comment: Why on earth are you using `pt` units? Most systems aren't calibrated to display them correctly.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to achieve what you want without Javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Autosizing textarea using prototype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477/autosizing-textarea-using-prototype)

Comment: You might want to have a look at the output of the [Fountain Scrippets plugin](http://fountain.io/scrippets). It accepts a Markdown-like text format for screenplays, and outputs... possibly HTML formatted with CSS to look like a screenplay, possibly text in a `<pre>` element with screenplay spacing. I'm not sure which.

Comment: Why do you use a `textarea` control to display dialogue? If you just put the content in a `div` element, it will automatically take the height needed for its content.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to get your screenplay text to display in a monospace font with multiple spaces preserved, you'd be better off using a different element with `white-space:pre` assigned to it:

#### HTML

```
<div class="screenplay">
EXT. FOREST / ELSEWHERE - DAY

Susan is on a cell-phone call. She smiles at Melissa, who walks by with two cups of coffee.

                        SUSAN (V.O.)
            Right now, this is probably our top pilot. But things change.
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.screenplay {
    white-space: pre;
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/GhMjq/

However, you might also want to take a look at the output of the [Fountain Scrippets plugin](http://fountain.io/scrippets). I believe this outputs screenplay snippets in sensible HTML that's formatted according to standard screenplay conventions using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery autoresize Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/autosize/) on keyup like [this jsfiddle exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/cha9chi/52JXS/)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('textarea').on('keyup',function() {
     $('textarea').autosize();
 });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

this code works for me, I hope it will help you,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<textarea  id="textarea" style="width: 140pt;  resize: none; overflow:hidden;">fdsf</textarea>

<script>
function setHeight()
{
var elem=document.getElementById("textarea");
var h=elem.offsetHeight;
var scrollHeight=elem.scrollHeight;
var innerHeight=elem.innerHeight;

if(scrollHeight>=h)
{
    elem.style.height=scrollHeight+"px";
}else
{
    elem.style.height=scrollHeight-2+"px";
}
}
setInterval(function(){setHeight()},30);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```