# JQuery - Snap text area to content size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a div and the user can click on a button to make the div grow in size and become editable:

```
$('#t4_post_item_' + $number).css("height", "500px");
```

When the user clicks the button again the div needs to snap back to the minimum possible size, this will likely be different to the original size as the user will enter some text.

How can i make the textarea snap back to the minimum possible size based on whats in the textarea?

Example:

The textarea starts at 200px in height, then grows to 500px when the button is clicker, then the user enters a bunch of text which takes up say .. 324px, how can i snap to that variable size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using auto should work for you:

```
$('#t4_post_item_' + $number).css("height", "auto");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xbtqmo0a/

Comment: It's definitely not working properly - its only snapping back to the original size not the new automatic one when i use auto

Comment: Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xbtqmo0a/ If that is too far from what you are trying to do, could you make a fiddle yourself so I can look?

Comment: I've changed it to a <textarea></textarea> rather than a div, it that seems to be causing the resize issues, yours does work fine with the div - I've just realised i have it as non-resizable ... I'm thinking its something to do with that property, will play around with it a bit

Comment: Okay good luck. Textarea might be a whole different battle, see [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477/autosizing-textarea-using-prototype)