# Textarea not resizing or expanding with carriage return

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, textarea

My textarea is not expanding when my cursor is at the bottom of the area and I press return to create a new line. I can expand some of my other textareas in my app, so I'm thinking there is some element around it that's preventing it from expanding/re-sizing when I type? Any thoughts?

Here is my html and rendered html

```html
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OverviewSummary, new { @class = "control-label" })
     <form id="OverviewSummarySubmit">
          @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.OverviewSummary, new { @class = "form-control input-lg", @style = "min-height: 64px; max-height: 460px; max-width: 500px; overflow: hidden", data_id = Model.YogaSpaceId, data_url = Url.Action("UpdateSummary", "ManageSpaces") })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OverviewSummary, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @style = "font-weight: bold;" })
     </form>
</div>



<textarea name="OverviewSummary" class="form-control input-lg valid" id="OverviewSummary" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="OverviewSummary-error" style="height: 90px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 64px; max-height: 460px; max-width: 500px;" rows="2" cols="20" data-val="true" data-id="3" data-val-maxlength-max="1500" data-val-maxlength="Maximum Length 1500 Characters." data-url="/ManageSpaces/3/UpdateSummary">This is at Alamo Square Park near Hayes Valley. The cat jumped over the roof to get the mouse.
I like trees!
When I jump its high!
</textarea>
```

here is the textarea with text

[image]

here is the textarea after I press return a couple of times (NO RE-SIZING!)

[image]

Comment: `textarea` doesn't resize on its own, you need to use some javascript for that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477/autosizing-textarea-using-prototype

Answer (score 0):

oops! I noticed I had this on the other pages that sized my textarea

```js
$('textarea').on('input', function () {
    $(this).outerHeight(20).outerHeight(this.scrollHeight);
});
$('textarea').trigger('input');
```

Answer (score 0):

in your css file put resize style to your textarea
**Like this:**

```
<style>
    textarea{resize:both;}
</style>
```

Comment: @user1186050 your textarea tag has style attr, you should add this **resize:both;** in it.