# Textarea automatically increase according to the text

Tags: javascript

I dynamically return the following table. Within the Table I have a column that returns a textarea as follows:

```js
var cars = [
   {DataRegisto: "2021-01-10 18:32:11", },
];

var cars1 = [
   {Designacao:  "asjdjas sjhdkasdkjasd jsakjdshkadjh jaksjdjhas sfddsfdsf sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd fsdf sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdfsdf", },
];
    
var linha1 = ``;
                        
Object.keys(cars).forEach(i=>{
        DataRegisto = cars[i].DataRegisto;
}) 
 
 linha1 += `
                           <tr class="table__row accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".demo1">
                           <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></button></td>
                           <td class="table__content" data-heading="Registo"> ${ DataRegisto }</td>
                           </tr>`;
               

 linha1 += `<tr>
                            <td colspan="12" class="hiddenRowww">
                            <div class="accordian-body collapse demo1" > 
                            
                            <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                            <tr class="info">   
                            <th class="table__heading">Designação</th>      
                            </tr>
                            </thead>`;
 
Object.keys(cars).forEach(i=>{

        Designacao = cars1[i].Designacao;

linha1 += `<td class="table__content" data-heading="Designação"><textarea class="area" rows="2" data-min-rows="2" name="Designaca[]">${Designacao}</textarea></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        </tbody>`;
                            
                        
                        })
 linha1 += `</table>
        
                        </div>
                        </td>
                        </tr>`;

$("#ediorc tbody").html(linha1);

$(document)
.on('keyup input keypress keydown change', '.area', function(e) {
   var tamanhoMin1 =  $(this).attr('rows') * $(this).css('line-height').replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, '');
   $(this)
   .css({'height': 'auto'});

   var novoTamanho1 = this.scrollHeight + parseFloat($(this).css("borderTopWidth")) + parseFloat($(this).css("borderBottomWidth"));
   if (tamanhoMin1 > novoTamanho1) novoTamanho1 = tamanhoMin1;
   $(this).css({'height': novoTamanho1});
});

$(".area")
.delay(0)
.show(0, function() {
    var el1 = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        el1.trigger('keyup');
    }, 100);        
});
```

```css
.hiddenRowww {
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.lado {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table id="ediorc" class="table">
  <thead> 
    <tr> 
      <th class="table__heading"><i class="fas fa-list"></i></th>
      <th class="table__heading">Registo</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is that the textarea does not increase according to the returned text as shown in the example above.

Can anyone help to understand the problem of textarea not automatically increasing according to the text?

Use this function to auto-expand textarea automatically:

```
$(document)
.on('keyup input keypress keydown change', '.area', function(e) {
   var tamanhoMin1 =  $(this).attr('rows') * $(this).css('line-height').replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, '');
   $(this)
   .css({'height': 'auto'});

   var novoTamanho1 = this.scrollHeight + parseFloat($(this).css("borderTopWidth")) + parseFloat($(this).css("borderBottomWidth"));
   if (tamanhoMin1 > novoTamanho1) novoTamanho1 = tamanhoMin1;
   $(this).css({'height': novoTamanho1});
});

$(".area")
.delay(0)
.show(0, function() {
    var el1 = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        el1.trigger('keyup');
    }, 100);        
});
```

But it's not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477/how-to-autosize-a-textarea-using-prototype

Comment: @chad_ I tested the example in the question you asked and it didn't work either

Comment: aww, too bad. I am working atm but can whip something up for you if this doesn't get answered before I'm free.

Comment: @chad_ OK thank you. I really appreciate that you could help me

Comment: OK, I think I made a working thing. Might need tweaks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could work.  Basically I'm using a `span` with `contentEditable` set, then sticking the value of the `span` into a hidden `form` `input` (so it can be posted with a `form` normally). The result `pre` is unnecessary in the end product but is there just to show what's going into the `form` `input` (spoiler: it's the `span` contents).

```js
const textArea = document.querySelector('.textarea')
const hiddenArea = document.querySelector('input[name=spanValue]')
const resultPre = document.querySelector('#result')
textArea.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', (e) => { 
  hiddenArea.value = textArea.innerText
  resultPre.innerText = hiddenArea.value
})
```

```css
.textarea {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  padding: 1px 6px;
}

.textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
  min-height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

/* Just for demo */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: "Heebo", sans-serif;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <span 
    class="textarea" 
    role="textbox" 
    contenteditable>
  </span>
  <input name="spanValue" type="hidden">
<form>
<br/>
Form value: <pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
if(window.attachEvent){
    observe = function(element, event, handler){ element.attachEvent('on'+event, handler); };
}else{
    observe = function(element, event, handler){ element.addEventListener(event, handler, false); };
}
function init(){
    var textAreas = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('textarea[data-adaptheight]'));
    textAreas.forEach(function(el){
        function resize(){
            var scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset ||
                (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollLeft;
            var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset ||
                (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
      el.style.resize = "none";
          el.style.overflow = 'hidden';
          el.style.boxSizing = el.style.mozBoxSizing = 'border-box';
            el.style.height = "auto";
            el.style.height = el.scrollHeight + 'px';
            window.scrollTo(scrollLeft, scrollTop);
        }
        observe(el, 'input', resize);
        resize();
    });
}

var cars = [{DataRegisto: "2021-01-10 18:32:11"}];
var cars1 = [{Designacao:  "asjdjas sjhdkasdkjasd jsakjdshkadjh jaksjdjhas sfddsfdsf sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd fsdf sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdfsdf"}]; 
var linha1 = ``;                   
Object.keys(cars).forEach(i=>{
    DataRegisto = cars[i].DataRegisto;
}) 
 
linha1 += `
    <tr class="table__row accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".demo1">
    <td><button onclick="runthis();" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></button></td>
    <td class="table__content" data-heading="Registo"> ${ DataRegisto }</td>
    </tr>`;
               

linha1 += `<tr>
    <td colspan="12" class="hiddenRowww">
    <div class="accordian-body collapse demo1" > 

    <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr class="info">   
    <th class="table__heading">Designação</th>      
    </tr>
    </thead>`;
 
Object.keys(cars).forEach(i=>{
    Designacao = cars1[i].Designacao;
    linha1 += `
        <td class="table__content" data-heading="Designação">
        <textarea data-adaptheight class="area" rows="2" data-min-rows="2" name="Designaca[]">${Designacao}</textarea>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>`;                                                        
});

linha1 += `</table>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>`;

$("#ediorc tbody").html(linha1);
$(".area").delay(0).show(0, function(){
    var el1 = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        el1.trigger('keyup');
        
    }, 100);        
});
function runthis(){
    setTimeout(function () {
        init();
    }, 0);
}
```

```css
.hiddenRowww {
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.lado {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table id="ediorc" class="table">
  <thead> 
    <tr> 
      <th class="table__heading"><i class="fas fa-list"></i></th>
      <th class="table__heading">Registo</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Your code but fixed up to work.